# Nuxt 3 i18n localePath not translating the url

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am having various problems with the routing system in Nuxt 3.

1. When I visit my website (/) it does not automatically put the language prefix while it should do that. I am using the "prefix" strategy.
2. I have a unique URL for each page by using this code:

```
<script setup>
defineI18nRoute({
  paths: {
    nl: '/blogs/my-blog',
    de: '/bloggt/my-blog',
    pl: '/blogi/my-blog',
    tr: '/bloglar/my-blog',
  }
})
</script>
```

but when I make a link to the route, it always stays in the "nl" language and it does not change.

```
<NuxtLink :to="localePath('/blogs/my-blog')" :title="$t('blogs_1_title')">
<span class="absolute inset-0"></span>
    {{ $t('blogs_1_title') }}
</NuxtLink>
```

I do see the prefix change i.e. nl, de, pl or tr but not the "text" of the url itself, in this case the word "blogs".

When I use the Vue browser plugin and check the routes, I do see the correct routes:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Been browsing the documentation but I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: localePath() accepts a second parameter that has to be the language..
you can use `const { locale } = useI18n();` to get the current locale and pass it there